# В миграции генерится один и тот же код

Tags: sql, symfony, миграция, entity, symfony4

Использую symfony 4.3
В проекте имеются разные сущности, которые отображаются на разные таблицы БД.
Но в процессе разработки при запуске команды doctrine:migrations:diff в миграции генерится кроме всего прочего один и тот же код.

```
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE user_users ALTER new_email TYPE VARCHAR(255)');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE user_users ALTER new_email DROP DEFAULT');
```

Если изменения в сущностях есть - этот код генерится вместе с другим SQL, если изменений нет генерится только этот код. Я уже пытался применять эту миграцию, но в следующих миграциях этот код все равно генерится как и раньше.

В сущности юзер это поле выглядит как обычно

```
/**
 * @var Email|null
 * @ORM\Column(type="user_user_email", name="new_email", nullable=true)
 */
private $newEmail;
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: `[diff] Generate a migration by comparing your current database to your mapping information.` Приведите результат `show create table` для прояснения ситуации.

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете кастомный тип

```
type="user_user_email"
```

но в комментарии к полю нет хинта, что это за тип. Поэтому при следующем diff доктрина видит просто `varchar(255)` и добавлят исправление в миграцию.

в класс вашего кастомного типа добавьте:

```
public function requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return true;
}
```

сделайте `diff` и примените миграцию.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, реализовал этот метод, сгенерировал и применил миграции и проблема исчезла. Я так понимаю реализация этого метода является обязательной для любого кастомного типа?